# Responsive two colored waves

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I been scratching my head trying to figure out how to do this using CSS.

I'm not opposed to doing this another way, but I am trying to figure out how to get this done overlapping and image or video and making it responsive.

[waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udy30.jpg)

Pen: https://codepen.io/skella1/pen/GRjNLzx

```
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e0efe3;
}

#wave:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 100% 50%;
        width: 340px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    right: -5px;
    top: 40px;
}

#wave:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 100% 50%;
        width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #e0efe3;
    left: 0;
    top: 27px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use this code it will work**

```css
    
    #wave {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e0efe3;
    }

    #wave:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 50%;
    width: 57%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    right: -5px;
    top: 40px;
    }

    #wave:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #e0efe3;
    left: 0;
    top: 27px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wave"/>
<div/>
```

Comment: This is neat. You can play with the widths of the #wave:before and #wave:after to get your desired wave.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's 

long-term value.

Comment: How would you flip it to achieve what I have in my image? The inverse of the bottom values?

Comment: Skell, if you increase a width to 100% in vawe class, also you need to increase width both of two classes of vawe before and vawe after classes in percent